# Switching Views using Xcode

Tags: xcode

Using Xcode do I need to create a new file for each view when it is connected to a button? Or does it work fine with just keeping the app under one h and m file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new file for each view. This will give you a new .h and .m file. Using MVC or single app view.

Answer (score 1):

iOS app development follow the model-view-control design pattern, and as such, you should always create a new control (.m and .h file) for each new view.